# in array inside of if statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I need to show a div when the value exists inside of the array, I have this code:

```
<?php if (in_array("odontologia basico", $s)) { ?>
    <li><a href="#1">Consulta odontol&oacute;gica</a></li>
<?php } else { ?>
    <li><a href="#1">Consulta m&eacute;dica</a></li>
<?php } if (in_array("alergologia", $s)) { ?>
    <li><a href="#alergia">Prueba de Alergia</a></li>
<?php } if (in_array("odontologia basico", $s)) { ?>
    <li><a href="#odonto">Odontograma</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

in the DB the row has these values:

```
$s = ("dermatologia", "alergologia", "pediatria");
```

and in the select statement the row:

```
$s = explode(', ',$row['s']);
```

but the div is not shown, I have three values( more or less values) but right now any is shown...can you help me with this please?

when I put print r this is shown in the page:

```
Array ( [0] => dermatologia [1] => alergologia [2] => pediatria )
```

Comment: Can you show an exact copy of the value of the row in the database?

Comment: Can you post a print_r($s); to see what values are in the array.

Comment: use print_r($s) to check you are getting right values, as @santy said

Comment: this is showed when I do it, please view the last part

Comment: The `print_r` was run on which variable? `$s` or `$row['s']`?

Comment: `print_r` run in this variable `$s`

Comment: You say "the div is not shown", but you're showing list items <li>, are they inside a div with css? Try this where you did the print_r: `echo(in_array("alergologia", $s) ? 'YES, alergologia is in the array' : 'NO, alergologia is NOT in the array');` What shows?

Comment: @Santy even the li is not shown and show me this: YES, alergologia is in the array

Comment: Meaning the PHP is working fine. You'll have to search in a different direction, it's either misplaced or some styling (css) is not done properly or blocks display.

Comment: well the entire list is inside of the second div that is not active when you see the page...so when you click in the second div show the list and below of the list is show the href of each li...maybe is because that?? I use bootstrap 2 in this project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already do it, here is how I can make it:

```
<?php print_r(in_array('dermatologia', $s) ? '
    <li><a href="#derm">Diagramas</a></li>' : '');  ?>
```

when I added the code (li) inside of the YES OR NO in array the code is show it and I need it too the `print_r()`